# how do you show one definite integral is less than another definite integral over the same region?

Tags: integration, inequality, proof-verification, integral-inequality

How do you show

$$ \int ^{b}_{a} f(x) \,dx \leq \int ^{b}_{a} g(x) \,dx$$

if you know f(x) and g(x) are continuous over [a,b] and $$f(x) \leq g(x)$$ for $${a \leq x \leq b}$$

Here is the way I would solve it.

Show $$ \int ^{b}_{a} f(x) \, dx \leq \int ^{b}_{a} g(x) \, dx$$
Show $$ \int ^{b}_{a} f(x) \, dx - \int ^{b}_{a} g(x) \, dx \leq 0$$
Show $$ \int ^{b}_{a} (f(x) - g(x)) \, dx  \leq 0$$

Since we know $$f(x) \leq g(x)$$ it follows that $$f(x) - g(x) \leq 0$$

which means:

Show $$ \int ^{b}_{a} \text{(something less than or equal to 0)} \, dx  \leq 0$$

But obviously, if you integrate something less than or equal to $0$ you are going to end up with something less than or equal to 0 [as was to be shown].

Is this a correct proof ?

Comment: Yes, this looks fine.

Comment: I don't think this is correct since you are using the theorem to proof the theorem, for with ${\rm h}(x)=0$, we have $({\rm f}(x)-{\rm g}(x))\leq {\rm h}(x)=0$ whenever $a \leq x \leq b$ and hence $\int_{a}^{b}({\rm f}(x)-{\rm g}(x))dx \leq \int_{a}^{b}{\rm h}(x)dx = 0$.

Comment: Yeah, this question is in need of what you consider as known results available in the proof and what you do not.

Comment: Where did h(x) come from all of a sudden ? Why can't we use 0 instead of h(x) ?

Comment: it seems roundabout way of doing the same thing.

Comment: Do not, at all cost, answer my comment, this could bring a relevant answer to be posted...

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets pickup from th moment you've got 
$$\int^b_a(f(x)-g(x))\,dx\leq 0$$

To show this let's consider a function $H(x)$ defined as follows

$$H(x)=\int^x_a(f(t)-g(t))\,dt.$$

It's obvious that $H(a)=0$. We know that a decreasing function is a function, which has negative derivative, but

$$H^\prime(x)=f(x)-g(x)\leq 0$$

This means $H(x)$ is decerasing on $[a,b]$ and subsequently $0=H(a)\geq H(x),\,\forall x\in[a,b]$.